# Generated apk with CI/CD integration crashed in the real android device

Tags: android, continuous-integration, build.gradle, apk, continuous-deployment

Generated apk with CI/CD integration crashed in the real android device.

I am trying to install the apk which was generated using the CI/CD tool. But unfortunately it not launching my app in the devices.

Note: Build which I have generated using the android studio is working fine with the same keystore.

Any thoughts on this? Why the apk not launching my app in the devices?

Note: I am using appcircle

Comment: What is the message?

Comment: Using android studio you can compare two apk files to find out the difference: Build->Analyze APK

Comment: @miladsalimi It shows the package name corrupt message in android 11. In android 10 failed to start several times. Restore it by clearing history. In v8.1.0 it failed to launch app without any message

Comment: @sdex How can I know the apks are differ. Are you mentioning this by the size?